# How can I get an OUT value from a MySQL SP when I may or may not have a query inside it?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, procedure

I have read tons of answers about getting OUT values in MySQL with PHP, but none of them helped me. I'm using PDO, MySQL and Procedures.

I am creating a login page. If user logs in, the procedure returns zero and the user information. If not, the procedure returns -999.

I have this following procedure for a login page:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`lvcs_ukpi`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Login`(IN `param_login` VARCHAR(30), IN `param_senha` VARCHAR(30), OUT `returnValue` INT)
    NO SQL
BEGIN

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Users
           WHERE LOWER(login) = LOWER(param_login)
             AND password = param_senha THEN

    SELECT *
      FROM Users
     where login = param_login
       and senha = param_senha;

     SET @returnValue = 0;

ELSE
    SET @returnValue = -999;
END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

In PHP, I'm trying to get the return value with:

```
  $sql = "CALL Login('" . $login . "','" . $senha . "', @returnValue)";
  $res1 = $conn->query($sql);
  $res2 = $conn->query("SELECT @returnValue");
  
  $records2 = $res2->fetch();
  $valor = $records2["@returnValue"];
```

And I'm getting the following:
`Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on bool in /home/lvcs/public_html/kpi_teste/index.php:51`

Can anybody give me some light? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Comment: Are you using `PDO` or `mysqli`?

Comment: @Barmar, I'm using PDO

Comment: Then enable `PDO::ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` so you get a detailed error message.

Comment: Nothing detailed....
Value of PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE: 1

Comment: Have you read [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), particularly Example #4?

Comment: That's `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`. You should enable exceptions so your script stops immediately when it gets a SQL error, and it will show the detailed error message. You can use `try/catch` to catch the errors if necessary.

Comment: @user1191247 Yes, but my case is a little more complicated because I also may or may not have a recordset with the output value.

Comment: It really isn't any more complicated. You need to fix the setting of your OUT param. `SET @returnValue = 0;` should be `SET returnValue = 0;`. And you haven't closed your `EXISTS(`. If you set `PDO::ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` as suggested by Barmar, you would be seeing meaningful error messages.